# eclipse doesn't detect errors on c file

Tags: eclipse

I'm writing a C file and Eclipse Juno doesn't detect errors in my code. I tested it by intentionally make an error code. When I'm writing Java file, it detects Java errors.

What can I do?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you downloaded the wrong version of eclipse.
Eclipse comes bundled with a lot of Java develoment tools, but C-ones are not included.
Easiest way is to download the bundled version for cc/c++ development

http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-cc-developers/lunar

You could also download the C Developer Tools as a eclipse plugin
http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/downloads.php

**Edit** In Eclipse, press Help > Install new software ... > Add ... 
Add at location: : http://download.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/releases/juno
Press OK.
Select the features, and thenpress next and so on

Comment: Can't I do it with eclipse juno? I have android sdk installed on this eclipse

Comment: Yes there is a version for Juno. Scroll down at http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/downloads.php and you'll find it

Comment: hey I did what you said and I Installed c/c++ development Tools And c/c++ development Tools SDK. I restarted eclipse.  still the same problem :(

Comment: I have to install "CDT optional Features" too ?

Comment: No, works for me. Does you file is saved with name.c?

Comment: ah okay, this does not work because the C file is in a java project and not  n a c project. This is not supported by default in Eclipse. You could give http://www.codexperiments.com/java/2010/08/an-hybrid-java-c-eclipse-project/ a try